# Activerecord strange behaviour while saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm Ruby Rails newbie, so maybe the answer to my question is obvious.

I have a problem saving record to my db.

The environment is Sinatra + Activerecord.

I have a content class:

```
class OldArticles < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :source
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

  def body
  self[:body]
  end

  def body=(value)
    self[:body] = value
  end

  def clean
    to_clean = self.body
    #some html sanify
    return to_clean
  end

  def save_cleaned
    store = self.clean
    self.body = "test"
    self.save!
    sleep 1
    self.body = store
    self.save!
  end

end
```

My OldArticle has a body field with some HTML. 
The clean method "clean" my HTML and return a string. The method is working.

The problem in on saving: the method "save_cleaned" is the only way I found to save my cleaned body, every other method is not working.

Case 1)

```
def save_cleaned
    self.body = self.body.clean
    self.save!
end
```

Nothing is saved to my dB.

Case 2)

```
def save_cleaned
    store = self.clean
    self.body = "test"
    self.save!
    self.body = store
    self.save!
end
```

"Test" is saved to my dB.

I don't understand why I must save some fake data string before saving the real content and why I must put a "sleep". Whitout the fake save and the sleep I cannot save my cleaned body back to the dB.

How is this possible?

Comment: What is the intent? Sometimes you want to save unclean HTML to the database and sometimes you want to save clean HTML?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear: i would like to save te cleaned version in the fastest way (case 1) but it doesn't work. It works only if I add the sleep and if I save fake data before my real data

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to use one of the ActiveRecord callbacks to scrub the HTML whenever it changes. I'd probably use a `before_validation` hook to make it easier to sanity check the HTML during validation. Something like this:

```
class OldArticles < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :source
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

  before_validation :scrub_body, :if => :body_changed?

private

  def scrub_body
    # scrub `self.body` into `sanitized_html` and then...
    self.body = sanitized_html
    true # Just in case `sanitized_html` is falsey...
  end

end
```

Then you'd work with the `body` attribute as usual, no accessor/mutator overrides or funky saving logic needed.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the saving. I'm cycling on this records, I must read object, scrub body and save.

Still the same problem: save! works only if before my HTML I save some plain text.

Comment: So you're reading `OldArticles` out of the database, scrubbing their HTML, and then saving them again? You should be able to `o.body_will_change!; o.save` in that case.

Comment: I found a solution: I must use ActiveRecord::Base.partial_writes = false. Without this save! doesn't work.